# How to wait till data is written on the other end of pipe

Tags: c, ipc, pipe

I am developing an application in C.
Parent and child process communicate through pipe.
Before writing to pipe, parent process execute another statements. In sample code, i have used sleep(10) to make delay.
In the child process, it should read the data from the pipe.
But data is not read on the read end of pipe in child process.

```
int main()
{
    int pid;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt","w");
    char *buff;
    int fd[2];
    int count = 0 ;
    pipe(fd);
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        ioctl(fd[0], FIONREAD, &count);
        fprintf(fp,"Value of count: %d ",count);
        buff = malloc(count);
        fprintf(fp,"\n TIME before read: %s",__TIME__);
        read(fd[0], buff, count);
        fprintf(fp,"\nbuffer: %s\n TIME after read %s", buff, __TIME__);
    }
    else{
        close(fd[0]);
        sleep(10);    //delay caused by application specific code replaced with sleep
        write(fd[1],"THIS is it",10);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

How to make child process wait till data is written on the other end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your pipe is opened in blocking mode, and you do nothing to change that, which is likely what you intended.

However, since the first thing you do is request the size of data waiting on the pipe, then blindly jump into reading that many bytes (which in all likelihood will be zero at the time that code executes since the parent hasn't written anything yet) you don't block, and instead just leave because you requested nothing.

There are a number of ways to do this, including a select-loop. If you would rather *block* on a read until data is available, then do so on a single byte and fill in the remaining data afterward.

This is by no means an example of how to do this *right*, but it is a short sample of how you can wait on a single byte, request the read-size of the pipe to get the rest of the data, read it, and continue this until the pipe has no data left and the parent shuts down their end:

I hope you find it helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main()
{
    int pid = 0;

    // create pipe pair
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // child side
        char *buff = NULL;
        char byte = 0;
        int count = 0;

        // close write side. don't need it.
        close(fd[1]);

        // read at least one byte from the pipe.
        while (read(fd[0], &byte, 1) == 1)
        {
            if (ioctl(fd[0], FIONREAD, &count) != -1)
            {
                fprintf(stdout,"Child: count = %d\n",count);

                // allocate space for the byte we just read + the rest
                //  of whatever is on the pipe.
                buff = malloc(count+1);
                buff[0] = byte;
                if (read(fd[0], buff+1, count) == count)
                    fprintf(stdout,"Child: received \"%s\"\n", buff);
                free(buff);
            }
            else
            {   // could not read in-size
                perror("Failed to read input size.");
            }
        }

        // close our side
        close(fd[0]);
        fprintf(stdout,"Child: Shutting down.\n");
    }
    else
    {   // close read size. don't need it.
        const char msg1[] = "Message From Parent";
        const char msg2[] = "Another Message From Parent";
        close(fd[0]);
        sleep(5); // simulate process wait
        fprintf(stdout, "Parent: sending \"%s\"\n", msg1);
        write(fd[1], msg1, sizeof(msg1));
        sleep(5); // simulate process wait
        fprintf(stdout, "Parent: sending \"%s\"\n", msg2);
        write(fd[1], msg2, sizeof(msg2));
        close(fd[1]);
        fprintf(stdout,"Parent: Shutting down.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Output**

```
Parent: sending "Message From Parent"
Child: count = 19
Child: received "Message From Parent"
Parent: sending "Another Message From Parent"
Parent: Shutting down.
Child: count = 27
Child: received "Another Message From Parent"
Child: Shutting down.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with getting number of bytes written to the pipe. You are getting it right after the fork(). If the read process executes first, it will contain no data (and the count will be zero). If the write process execute first, it will contain some data.

> How to make child process wait till data is written on the other end?

Since you opened the pipe in blocking mode, you should read as much data as possible, and not try to get the size of written data.

---

Here is your modified example that waits for a full message :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
int main()
{
int pid;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("test.txt","w");
char *buff = malloc(1024);
int fd[2];
int count = 0 ;
pipe(fd);
pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)
        {
                close(fd[1]);

                int i = 0;

                while ( i < 10 )
                {
                    fprintf(fp,"\n TIME before read: %s \n",__TIME__);
                    read(fd[0], buff+i, 1);
                    ++ i;
                }

                fprintf(fp,"Full message received!\nbuffer: %s\n TIME after read %s\n", buff, __TIME__);
        }
        else{
                close(fd[0]);
                sleep(10);    //delay caused by application specific code replaced with sleep
                write(fd[1],"THIS is it",10);
        }
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats right, but parent write variable size data each time, thats why i have used ioctl to get size of the data on the pipe. Can I block the ioctl till data received on the pipe?

Comment: @Ajay No, there are no ways to block the `ioctl()`.

Comment: @Ajay Honestly if sizing is important I would strongly suggest *against* utilizing `ioctl()` for this information. Literally from the time you invoke it until the time you follow up with a read-op the size could already be invalid due to more data written from the other end of the pipe. If you want to read the num-bytes the parent is going to send, then make that part of your *protocol* (the first four byte are a 32-bit network-byte-order message-length, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I think after

```
ioctl(fd[0], FIONREAD, &count);  
the count is 0.  

read(fd[0], buff, count) will get no data.  

try   
read(fd[0], buff, 10)
```

Comment: I have used ioctl for determining the size of data on end of pipe as data sent by the parent process is of variable length.

Comment: @Ajay correct, but at the time you hit it, there is *no* data in the pipe yet. Therefore you end up requesting *zero* bytes, which does not block.

Comment: @WhozCraig Is there any way so that, ioctl(xxxx) function waits till there is data available on the end of pipe i.e. exactly same way as read() waits till data available.

Comment: @Ajay not using `ioctl()` that I'm aware of, but it shouldn't matter. If you're worried about sizing your buffer you can always block on a [*single*-byte read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196784/how-to-wait-till-data-is-written-on-the-other-end-of-pipe/15197369#15197369), and on success, slurp up whatever is left in the pipe. Either that or just make a big hulking buffer and read into that. The choice is ultimately yours.